# como comparar fechas y horas con php

Tags: php, mysql

quiero comprar las fechas y horas por ejemplo:
las facturas recibidas de las 8:30 a las 13:30 que estén "en tiempo" si se entregan hasta las 18:00 hrs, del mismo día, sino están "fuera de tiempo"

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT factura, fechafactura, cliente, hrasalida, hraentrega, hrallegada, chofer, vehiculo, direccion from facturacion where estatus='ENTREGA DOMICILIO' order by fechafactura DESC LIMIT 70");
$cont=mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($cont>0)
{

    while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $hrini=$array[3];
        $hrfin=$array[4];
        $diferencias = strtotime($hrfin) - strtotime($hrini);
        //$time = time();
            $mins=$diferencias/60;
        //$fin= date("i", $diferencias);    
        //$diferencias = time();

        echo'<tr><td>'.$array[0].'</td><td>'.$array[1].'</td><td>'.$array[2].'</td><td>'.$array[3].'</td><td>'.$array[4].'</td><td>'.$array[5].'</td><td>'.$array[6].'</td><td>'.$array[7].'</td><td>'.$array[8].'</td><td>'.$mins.' minutos'. '</td></tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo'<tr><td>No hay registros</td></tr>';
}
echo '<table>';
/***************************************TERMINA FACTURAS*/
?>
```

Comment: muestra tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: Si trabajas SQL podria ser algo asi facturacion.fechafactura BETWEEN '".$_POST["fechai"]."' AND '".$_POST["fechaf"]."'

Comment: acabo de añadir el código , la horaentrega la almaceno en la variable hrfin , con la cual sabre si esta a tiempo o no, pero como la compararía que este antes de las 18:00 del mismo día que se creo la factura , la fecha de factura la tomo del campo fechafactura

Comment: Los fragmentos de código que se anexan a las preguntas deberán ser en texto y NO en una captura/imagen

Comment: En qué formato devuelve la hora? `H:m:s d/M/Y`?

Comment: en la tabla del código que subí me devuelve la hora de entrega en H:m:s 0000:00:00

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que para el tratamiento de de tiempos y fechas , utilices [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), facilitaría mucho tu trabajo y es super simple.

Comment: @elevadoatres esa solución es en javascript, el OP realiza su pregunta definiendo PHP.